# PostGIS to dissolve all features

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have a multi polygon with spatial field layer with and 3000 records and I want to use dissolve all in 1 record.

On DISSOLVE algorithm in QGIS you have a choose to dissolve all features from layer that I want with PostGIS.

After the query I want to have one record and this record have all.

I test this query :

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_union(geom))).geom::geometry(POLYGON,2100) FROM public.parcel1
```

but don't work; don't create me one record with all features.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: select st_union(geom) geom from parcel1

Comment: the query you have is breaking up the spatial table into many singlepart features

Comment: @Ziggy that export if I use your details is multipolygon or polygon ?

Comment: "that export"? dont know what you are talking about. it will be a multipolygon

Answer (score 1):

To condense all the geometries in a table to one single geometry, you can pass an array to ST_Union:

```
SELECT ST_Union(ARRAY(SELECT geom FROM tbl))
```

Comment: `ST_Union` has an aggregate function variant, so you should just be able to use `SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM tbl`

Comment: @dr_jts that's what we use